# ASP.NET Core 3 implement IAuthorizationPolicyProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

I’ve changed the target framework of my ASP.NET Core application from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.0.

My app contains a custom auth policy provider (`IAuthorizationPolicyProvider`) implementation.
Since .NET Core 3 the IAuthorizationPolicyProvider interface contains a new method `Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetFallbackPolicyAsync()`.

What is the difference between `Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetDefaultPolicyAsync();` and `Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetFallbackPolicyAsync()`. And how should `GetFallbackPolicyAsync` be implemented? Should it be implemented like `GetDefaultPolicyAsync`?

Currently my class implements the `GetDefaultPolicyAsync` method like this:

```
public CustomPolicyProvider( [NotNull] IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options )
    => _fallbackPolicyProvider = new DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider( options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(options) ) );

public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetDefaultPolicyAsync() => _fallbackPolicyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync();
```

Comment: I don't know what this method is used for, but in the sample class MinimumAgePolicyProvider, GetFallbackPolicyAsync is simply called on the fallbackPolicyProvider [src](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/56ffc6b58210292a18f548bf4eddff193f73a4d6/src/Security/samples/CustomPolicyProvider/Authorization/MinimumAgePolicyProvider.cs#L30)

Comment: @J.Loscos Thanks for the link! I totally missed that there are samples for this.

Comment: I think, but this is just an educated guess based on the GitHub issues and samples around the change, that Default is where the policy isn't explicitly handled by your policy provider and fallback is where the Authorization attribute doesn't specify a Policy at all.

Comment: Source: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/14834

Comment: @pwdst You are right. I found this in the documentation "Alternatively, all endpoints can be configured to require authorization without [Authorize] or RequireAuthorization by configuring a FallbackPolicy. The FallbackPolicy is different from the DefaultPolicy. The DefaultPolicy is triggered by [Authorize] or RequireAuthorization, while the FallbackPolicy is triggered when no other policy is set. FallbackPolicy is initially configured to allow requests without authorization."  Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30

Comment: StackOverflow allows you to answer your own questions so if you answer it based on your comment above and mark it as accepted it will both get you more reputation and may help other people find the answer in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs for dotnet core 3.0/3.1:
[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

```
public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetFallbackPolicyAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult<AuthorizationPolicy>(null);
}
```

Comment: in .NET Core 6 it is not working. Getting this exception **ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'policy')**